# How do you find a plane that is both parallel and a distance of X units from a given plane

Tags: geometry

I've been asked to come up with equations for two parallel planes that are X units apart. I've come up with the plane $x+z-1=0$ and a parallel plane $x+z+4=0$. Would it be correct to say these planes are 5 units apart since the $d$ constant is increased by 5?

I calculated the distance between the point $(1,0,0)$ on the 1st plane and the 2nd plane and got $3.54$ which I guess proves that the the planes are not 5 units apart. But if that's the case, I'm not sure how else to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Find the normal vector to your first plane, which is $\vec{n} = (1,0,1)$. The unit vector in this direction is $\vec{u} = \frac{\vec{n}}{|\vec{n}|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,1)$. Now pick a point on the first plane, for example, you already mentioned $(1,0,0)$. Not just add $5$ times the unit normal vector to this point to get a point which is 5 units away from the plane:

$$ (1,0,0) + \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,1) = \left( 1 + \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}, \; 0, \; \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$$

Now just find the plane which is parallel and goes through this point. In other words, plug this point in to the equation $x + z + d = 0$ and solve for $d$.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of using the unit vector. I followed your advice and got the vector $x+z-8.08=0$, then checked the distance between $(1,0,0)$ from the initial plane to the new one and it was indeed 5. Thanks for your help!